# How can I put HTML table inside a dropdownbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I put HTML table inside a dropdownbox? So, something like:

```
<select>
     <table></table>
</select>

or

<select>
    <option>
        <table></table>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried, what do you want to acheive, do you want each cell to be selectable or the whole table etc etc

Comment: The standard is going to say no, but what happens when you try it in a browser?

Comment: is dropdown your only option? If not I will say go for accordion ...it will be lot easier..

Comment: @FrankB Please do not enforce to do something that will end up in invalid HTML.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I'm not enforcing anything. I'm just asking him what happens when he tries it in a browser. The point of the comment is to find out if he's even tried anything, and if not to encourage him to do so. He'll see if it works or not really quickly by giving it a try. I never said that he should, or if it works go for it, I simply asked him what happens when he tries to do it.

Comment: @FrankB OK, I can see that. But the Content Model of `option` is *text* so it should not work in any browser. And I also meant more like *encourage* than *enforce*.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I feel that trying it and seeing it break will probably teach him this better than us simply telling him it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS and HTML this is not possible.

javascript is probably your best way to approach this. Using Jquery will also help your javascript tremendously

Comment: How to do that? Do you know any website, or Have a sample code? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: No, because I have never seen a reason to do this

Answer (score 0):

You will need some custom self-made element if you want to do this. There are no other HTML tags allowed in an `<option>` tag.

Look for example at javascript libraries that are enhancing the standard select element, for instance [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Maybe you can get a little inspiration there on how to implement your table-logic.

Comment: How do I create a custom tag, I never made sofar?

Comment: A little Javascript / jQuery skill will be needed to achieve this. You have to basically simulate a select by creating an own solution consisting of standard HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do such that..you have to stimulate that.

You need to construct a div with multiple rows and add down arrow to the first row to make it look like dropdownlist.

Comment: Make sense. I can have dropdown in 1 div tag, and table in another div tag. After that, I can have a javascript that hides/show HTML table-div, depending on requirement.

Comment: Make Sense. I can do something like:

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible using the `select`-tag only. Within this tag only `optgroup`- and `option`-tags are allowed. See on w3c.org: "[17.6 The SELECT, OPTGROUP, and OPTION elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)".

When we go further to the `option`-tag, you'll see that the *Content Model* only allows `text` within this element. Again on w3c.org: "[4.10.12 The option element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-option-element)"

So the only way to get this one going is to create an element that looks and behaves similar to the `option`-tag using other HTML elements.

In this [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKDTY/) you can see an example, how a possible solution could look like. This one works without JavaScript, as the content is displayed on `:hover`. But of course you can change this to an `click`-event using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Okay, let me try that. I will post a code, once I will be done. Thx.